# how can i overwrite a directory?

Tags: git

I've cloned a online project that is not mine, and if i run the command once more i get the fata:: destination pat 'foo' already exists and is not a empty path

I've looked thru the commands to pass with the command for clone, am i overlooking something? i would like it to just overwrite the whole filedirectory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What are you trying to do by cloning twice?  If you want an updated version `git pull` inside the old repository.  If you want a fresh checkout, then remove or rename the old one manually.  `git` doesn't want to overwrite existing directories because it could easily lead to data loss.